# apollo-federation validate input field in another subgraph

Tags: apollo, apollo-server, express-graphql, apollo-federation, apollo-gateway

in microservice project I have configured graphql, apollo-federation, apollo-gateway.

#### Menu service

```
mutation createMenu(location_id: ID!): Menu
```

#### Location service

```
type Location{
    id: ID!
}
type Query{
    location(id: ID!): Location
}
```

in menu create resolver I want to get location data

```
storeMenu(_, location_id, __, ___){
    // how to get location data because location is located in external service
}
```

I am familiar with @key, @external, extends. But this is for type object not works with input type